# shinyWidgets pickerInput width issue overflow off sidebar

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, shinywidgets

I am using shinyWidgets `pickerInput` within a flexdashboard sidebar. My issue is that when the options in the `pickerInput` are too wide they get cut off within the width of the sidebar which makes it so you cannot read the options, see which are selected, or see the `deselect all` button. Is there a way to have the `pickerInput` dropdown overflow off of the sidebar and onto the body of the page?

As an intermediate solution I have found that you can use:

```
choicesOpt = list(
      content = stringr::str_trunc(sort(unique(COLUMN_NAME)), width = 25))
```

To truncate the text in the `pickerInput` so that you are able to see which options are selected and all of the buttons but you are still not able to read each option fully.

**Edit:**

Adding reprex - Looking to have the filter drop down open over the body so that everything is visible.

````
---
title: "TEST"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)


Name <- c("LONNGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG TEXXTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.frame(Name, Age)

```




Sidebar {.sidebar}
=======================================================================

### Filters

```{r}




pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = sort(unique(df$Name)),
  selected = sort(unique(df$Name)),
  multiple = TRUE,
  options = list(
    `actions-box` = TRUE,
     `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(df$Name))) -1),`count-selected-text` = "All Selected")
)

```


TEST
=======================================================================

Row 
-------------------------------------

```{r}
filtered_data <-
    reactive ({
      req(input$name)

      df %>%
        filter(Name %in% input$name) 

    })

renderDataTable(filtered_data(), class = 'cell-border stripe',
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center',width = '100px', targets = "_all"))),fillContainer=TRUE)
```
````

Comment: You could add some CSS to the sidebar div or pickerInput to increase the z-index. So it does not get cutoff.

Comment: Which div would I use? I have been trying `tags$div(tags$style(HTML( ".shiny-input-container{z-index:1000;}")))` but not getting anywhere

Comment: If you update your question with a small reprex illustrating the problem. I would be able to assist.

Comment: ty - just added a reprex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have unintended side effects but here's a workaround to force the picker dropdown to not get cutoff.

You can add your own css class to the Sidebar section inside the `{}`. I used `.my-class` as a placeholder. Then I inserted a css chunk and added `.my-class` to the `.section.sidebar` classes from flexdashboard. If you don't do that then that css will overwrite the class. Most likely because it's loaded afterwards.

Also in the reprex provided, for whatever reason the choices were the not the actual values but instead the level positions.

So I used `sort(unique(Name))` instead of `sort(unique(df$Name))`

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
.section.sidebar.my-class {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Sidebar {.sidebar .my-class}
=======================================================================

...
````

[image]

**Option 2: Truncate choices**

The above option works as long as the height of the sidebar does not exceed the height of the browser window. Ideally you want `overflow-x: visible` and `overflow-y: scroll`. However I'm not sure if that's possible on the same div with position fixed.

Instead you could truncate your options so they fit in the window. If you want more text to be displayed you can increase the width of the sidebar.

```
cs = sort(unique(Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = cs,
  selected = cs,
  multiple = TRUE,
  options = list(
    `actions-box` = TRUE,
     `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(df$Name))) -1),`count-selected-text` = "All Selected"
    ),
  choicesOpt = list(
    content = stringr::str_trunc(cs, width = 18)
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: It does appear that when you have too many input boxes you can no longer scroll down  in the sidebar when using `overflow: visible`

Comment: @user3249770 I see what you mean. I made some changes to give you another option. Otherwise, I'd suggest opening a new question with a css / javascript tag. I'm sure there's a non-trivial workaround using js.

Comment: thanks yeah I made a new post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745536/flexdashboard-sidebar-pickerinput-overflow-with-scrollbar]- didnt think to include a js tag, will add

Comment: whoops - I see you already figured out the truncate solution in the initial question.