# Flexdashboard sidebar pickerInput overflow with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, shiny, flexdashboard

In my previous question [shinyWidgets pickerInput width issue overflow off sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74732892/shinywidgets-pickerinput-width-issue-overflow-off-sidebar) I was able to resolve an issue where pickerInput boxes in the sidebar where the values were too wide would get cut off in the sidebar. However by using `overflow: visible;` to fix this I am now unable to scroll on the y-axis when there are more input boxes than the size of the browser window. Is there a way to use `overflow: visible;` as well as be able to scroll in the y-axis?

Reprex:

````
---
title: "TEST"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)


Name <- c("LONNGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG TEXXTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.frame(Name, Age)

```




```{css, echo=FALSE}
.section.sidebar.my-class {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Sidebar {.sidebar .my-class}
=======================================================================

### Filters

```{r}






pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)


pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)
```


TEST
=======================================================================

Row 
-------------------------------------

```{r}
filtered_data <-
    reactive ({
      req(input$name)

      df %>%
        filter(Name %in% input$name) 

    })

renderDataTable(filtered_data(), class = 'cell-border stripe',
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center',width = '100px', targets = "_all"))),fillContainer=TRUE)
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/shinySidebarScrollbar.html) I solved the same problem for the **shinyWidgets** dropdowns. The solution uses JavaScript to change the CSS property `overflow-y` according to whether the dropdown is opened.

Here is the same solution for the picker input. First change the CSS property `overflow-y` of the `.sidebar` class to `auto`:

```css
.section.sidebar.myclass {
  overflow-y: auto
}
```

Then, assuming the id of your picker input is `THEPICKERINPUTID`, add this JavaScript code in a `js` chunk (i.e. ```` ```{js} ````):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#THEPICKERINPUTID').on('show.bs.select', function() {
    $(".sidebar").css("overflow-y", "visible");
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function() {
    $(".sidebar").css("overflow-y", "auto");
  });
});
```