# Flexdashboard sidebar pickerInput overflow hijacking scrollbar

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I previously used the response in this question [Flexdashboard sidebar pickerInput overflow with scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745536/flexdashboard-sidebar-pickerinput-overflow-with-scrollbar) to modify `pickerInputs` with wide values so that all value names in the filter would be visible using JS. I have recently come across an issue with this where if the sidebar is long enough to have a scrollbar and you scroll on the sidebar at all and then click a `pickerInput` that uses the JS the entire sidebar moves to the default position. The issue with this is if you have a lot of filters and are on a smaller screen, when you click on a filter to open it, it moves to a position that you cannot view. I have included a reprex where the third filter causes this behavior. Looking to resolve the sidebar scroll hijacking that occurs while clicking on the JS wide filters.

````
---
title: "TEST"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)


Name <- c("LONNGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG TEXXTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.frame(Name, Age)

```

```{js}
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#name1').on('show.bs.select', function() {
    $(".sidebar").css("overflow", "visible");    
        $(".sidebar").css("z-index", "10000");
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function() {
    $(".sidebar").css("overflow-y", "auto");
  });
});
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=======================================================================

### Filters

```{r}

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name,
  multiple = TRUE)


pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name1",
  label = "Third Filter",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name,
  multiple = TRUE,
   options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                 `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(unique(df$Name, split=";")) -1),`count-selected-text` = "All"))

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)

pickerInput(
  inputId = "name",
  label = "test",
  choices = df$Name,
  selected = df$Name)
```

TEST
=======================================================================

Row 
-------------------------------------

```{r}
filtered_data <-
    reactive ({
      req(input$name)

      df %>%
        filter(Name %in% input$name) 

    })

renderDataTable(filtered_data(), class = 'cell-border stripe',
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center',width = '100px', targets = "_all"))),fillContainer=TRUE)
```
````

Comment: I ran your code and I'm not sure to understand the problem. First, shouldn't you use `"auto"` instead of `"hidden"`? With `"hidden"` there's no scrollbar anymore. If this is another problem, could you rephrase it please?

Comment: Edited - it should have been "auto" there.

Comment: And so what is the problem now?

Comment: If you scroll the sidebar and then click on a filter with the JS attached the entire sidebar scroll moves. This only occurs when you move the scrollbar from its initial position. So if you load the reprex and click the third filter it is fine. But if you then scroll the sidebar and click the third filter you will notice the scroll moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, when setting `overflow` to `visible`, the sidebar jumps to its initial position, and it is no longer scrollable so there's no JavaScript way to scroll it.

That said, setting a negative top margin seems to give a nice result:

````
```{css}
.section.sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
```    

```{js}
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#name1').on('show.bs.select', function() {
      var $sidebar = $(".sidebar");
      var x = - $sidebar.scrollTop();
      $sidebar.css("margin-top", x + "px");
      $sidebar.css("overflow", "visible");
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function() {
      var $sidebar = $(".sidebar");
      $sidebar.css("margin-top", "0px");
      $sidebar.css("overflow-y", "auto");
  });
});
```
````

***Note:*** you have some duplicated ids in your code (`"name"`), and this is bad.

Comment: This is great and seems to be working! I added `$(".sidebar").css("z-index", "100");` under the `show.bs.select` function as it was popping out underneath the right side table but everything looks good now. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to change the z-index of only the filter dropdown? I am running into an issue using `$(".sidebar").css("z-index", "100");` where the filter dropdown shows over the navbar but the entire sidebar is also showing through. Tried `$(".dropdown-menu open").css("z-index", "100");` to no avail.

Comment: @user3249770 I don't know. I encountered this issue and that's why I set the z-index to 0.