# Shiny selectInput/pickerInput with long names should overflow sidebar

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinywidgets, bs4dash

I want to built a shiny app with `bs4Dash` in sidebar layout. The sidebar contains a dropdown selection menu with items that have long names. Once I open the dropdown, I would like the full item name to be visible, i.e. overflowing the dashboard's body. The names are cut at the sidebar border by default (`shiny::selectizeInput`) or the dropdown content is right-aligned to the sidebar border and the start of the item name is off-screen to the left (`shinyWidgets::pickerInput`).

This is how the app looks (updated 2022-12-16):

[image: App with pickerInput open]

[image: App with selectInput open]

I tried to apply the solution for a `flexdashboard` described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74732892/shinywidgets-pickerinput-width-issue-overflow-off-sidebar),
but could not get it working.

Thanks for your help!

Here is a reproducible example of my app:

```
# app.R
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(shinyWidgets)

vec_long_items <- sapply(1:10, function(i) {
  paste("START", paste(sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
})

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = bs4DashNavbar(
      title = "Long items to select", disable = TRUE, controlbarIcon = NULL
    ),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(
      skin = "white",
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
        inputId = "in1", label = "shinyWidgets::pickerInput", choices = vec_long_items
      ),
      shiny::selectInput(
        inputId = "in2", label = "shiny::selectInput", choices = vec_long_items
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(tableOutput("out_text"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$out_text <- renderTable(data.frame(items = vec_long_items))
  },
  options = list(launch.browser = FALSE)
)
```

My sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] bs4Dash_2.1.0 shiny_1.7.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7         shinyWidgets_0.7.5 digest_0.6.29      later_1.3.0        mime_0.12          R6_2.5.1           lifecycle_1.0.2    xtable_1.8-4       jsonlite_1.8.0     magrittr_2.0.3
[11] cachem_1.0.6       rlang_1.0.5        cli_3.4.0          fontawesome_0.3.0  promises_1.2.0.1   jquerylib_0.1.4    bslib_0.4.0        ellipsis_0.3.2     tools_4.1.0        httpuv_1.6.5
[21] fastmap_1.1.0      compiler_4.1.0     memoise_2.0.1      htmltools_0.5.2    sass_0.4.2
```

Comment: What about the solution I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74750604/1100107)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stephane. However, I could not translate it to a shiny app. Could you maybe paste a minimal shiny app with inline CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Try this css:

```
css <- ".main-sidebar, .main-sidebar .sidebar .os-viewport, .os-host-overflow, .os-host-overflow>.os-padding {overflow: visible !important;}"
```

i.e.

```r
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(css))
      ),
```

and

```r
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
        inputId = "in1", label = "shinyWidgets::pickerInput", choices = vec_long_items, 
        options = pickerOptions(dropdownAlignRight = TRUE)
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane!
This works for pickerInput :-)

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent, any tips to get this to work with `bslib::sidebar` / `bslib::sidebar_layout`? I tried [your other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74750604/1100107) too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a CSS property for pickerInput that improves the output. Change the body as follows:

```
# ...
body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
        .dropdown-menu.show {
          display: contents;
        }
      "))
      ),
      tableOutput("out_text")
    )
# ...
```

Now there is a scrollbar to look at the complete element. Not what I wanted but already better.

[image: App with pickerInput having dropdown-x-scrollbar]

I am still looking for an "overflow-solution" :-)